# Is there a way in matrix math notation to show the 'flip up-down', and 'flip left-right' of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, terminology

Title says it all - is there an accepted mathematical way in matrix notation to show those operations on a matrix?

Thanks.

Comment: For a matrix $M$, will $DM$ and $MD$ suffice for up-down and left-right flips, respectively, where $D$ is the unit anti-diagonal matrix?

Comment: @VF1 Yeah, that can do. I suppose there is no 'notation' per se then for those operations, correct? (eg, nothing like $T$ for transpose).

Comment: The [APL programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_syntax_and_symbols#Monadic_functions) uses $⌽M$ for the left-right flip of $M$, and $⊖M$ for the up-down flip, but these notations are not common outside of the APL community. You are, of course, free to invent your own notation, and long as it is reasonably clear and you explain it.

Comment: @Spacey no - nothing widely used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} d & c \\ b & a\end{pmatrix}.$$

In general, left-multiplying by the anti-diagonal identity matrix swaps all rows. Right-multiplying swaps columns.

Comment: Very cool, thanks!

Comment: But there is no 'notation' per se for those operations, like $T$ for transpose, correct?

Comment: Nope. It's not a commonly-performed operation, but left/right multiplication by orthonormal matrices is fairly common and well-understood.

Comment: This matrix is also known as the "exchange matrix": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix

Comment: This approach only applies to square matrices. For rectangular matrices, there is no simple matrix operation for it. Just specify the flip by a defined notation.